# Significance of "over" in this context

Tags: sentence-construction

> we are going to go all the way **over** to the east coast.

Will the omission of **over**  change the meaning?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Will the omission of over change the meaning?**

**Yes,** if you omit over it takes away the emphasis of how far they are travelling. The basic meaning remains the same. However the author is trying to express the effort involved in get to this location, which would be removed with the omission.

**Over** in this case is a preposition meaning **OTHER SIDE**.